# Angular2. Компиляция готового приложения на продакшн

Tags: javascript, angular2

Ребят подскажите каким образом мне собрать готовый проект(angular2) на продакшн? То-есть минифицировать все js файлы, вытащить все используемые файлы из node_modules, которые использует приложение и так далее.

Comment: таки воспользоваться системой сборки

Comment: для angular 2 разрабатывается официальный инструмент генерации и сборки проектов https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: @kmv Спасибо =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать для этого Webpack. Как для дебага, так и для продакшена. Конфиг webpack для angular 2 для продакшена можно посмотреть на этой странице https://github.com/damienbod/Angular2WebpackVisualStudio

Comment: Пример использования был бы очень кстати в вашем ответе. )